# Mesh looks wrong after import to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: mesh, export, unreal-engine

I have imported a mesh into Unreal Engine 4 but for some reason the character's eyes aren't visible. Sometimes one shows from an angle.
They aren't separate objects or anything so I don't understand what the problem is.

He doesn't seem to be smooth shaded any more either. Maybe it's connected?

Also, he has lost his specular colouring and just has basic material.

[image: How he looks in Blender]
[image: in Unreal 4]

[image]

EDIT:

Still no luck. I recalculated the normals but doing that did strange things to parts of the mesh. I then checked the normals with the blue lines and they all seemed to be facing outwards anyway.
I realised I hadn't done a UV unwrap. So tried that and then exported again.
Doesn't seem to have changed anything.
I noticed that the eyes are there but only one has the correct colour, and that they disappear when I apply an animation to the character.
Does this shed any light?

[image]

Comment: Try to recalculate the normals of the eyes in Bleneder.

Comment: Are you exporting to FBX?

Comment: Yes. Exported to FBX. What will recalculating do? I'm new to this. I was wondering if it may be something to do with the specular setting? I think I put it quite high on the eyes.

Comment: No luck yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: Apologies. Found another way to check the normals that was clearer. There's a setting called 'backface culling' under the Materials tab. I click that and the eyes disappeared like they do in UE4. So I Recalculated the eyes to outside, and they no longer disappear.